# Can Egg Moves still be taught through the Nursery without Breeding?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes, pokemon-eighth-generation

From Bulbapedia's [Egg Move](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Egg_Move) page:

> In Sword and Shield, if two Pokémon of the same species are placed
> together in the Nursery and if one of the Pokémon has an empty move
> slot and the other knows an Egg Move, the Pokémon with the empty slot
> will learn the Egg Move. This will occur even if the Pokémon are the
> same gender.

Does this also work in Brilliant Diamond and Shining Pearl, or do I have to EV train a newly bred Azurill with Belly Drum and Aqua Jet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonBDSP/comments/r1cn5j/passing_egg_moves_in_nursery/), **YES**.

The mechanic works the same as Sword/Shield, so this should be the official rule from Generation VIII onward.

Also because that rule you quoted is (actually) valid for Generation VIII, and Pokemon BDSP are in Generation VIII.

Comment: Tried it with two males Cloyster, to pass down Rock Blast and it did work! Thanks :)